# Start/Stop Amazon RDS instance using C#

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to Stop/Start an Amazon RDS instance from C# code using the AWS SDK?

I am able to start/stop an Amazon EC2 instance but I am unable to find anything for Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stop the RDS instance using .NET SDK. Have a look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RDS/TRDSStopDBInstanceRequest.html) link.

Refer the [Amazon.RDS.Model Namespace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html) in API documentation for further details.

Comment: Its about stop, StopDBInstanceRequest

Comment: i am able to stop and start. But i am unable to login with admin user

Comment: i restarted aws rds(mysql) after that i am unable to connect from lambda and from my machine(using workbench) but both worked well before restart. Is this aws issue?

Comment: Updated like for `Amazon.RDS.Model Namespace` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/N_Amazon_RDS_Model.htm